# How can I show session array items in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

How can I make something like this below work?

```
<?PHP

$_SESSION['signup_errors']['test1'];
$_SESSION['signup_errors']['test2'];
$_SESSION['signup_errors']['test3'];
$_SESSION['signup_errors']['test4'];

foreach ($_SESSION['signup_errors'] as $key => &$value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh I got it, I didn't have the values set in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, but your setup lines don't actually assign any values.

```
$_SESSION['signup_errors']['test1'] = 'value1';
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you haven't assigned `$_SESSION['signup_errors']` a value, meaning there were no errors I guess. You should put the following line above the error-checking code:

```
$_SESSION['signup_errors'] = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not actually assigning any values to the elements in the session array in that section of code, $_SESSION is not returned as an array, therefore the foreach is receiving an empty variable and throwing an error.

If you are seeing the error message " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " and you know the session does contain values that you've set, make sure the session is started, using the php command  session_start();

then you will be able to loop through the session array and see the key & their values